# How to group 'each do' output by parent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am currently using the acts_as_tree gem and wish to display all my category names, separated by parent category names. Here is what I have tried.

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
<h4><%= category.parent.name if category.parent %></h4>
<%= category.name%>
<% end %>
```

It doesn't work because the parent titles are being repeated for every child. What I wish to achieve is parents only displayed once, followed by its children as such.

Parent 1

- Parent 1 Child 1
- Parent 1 Child 2
- Parent 1 Child 3

Parent 2

- Parent 2 Child 1
- Parent 2 Child 2
- Parent 2 Child 3

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first group `categories` together by the `parent` they have in common, using the [`group_by` method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) for enumerables; e.g.

```
@categories.group_by(&:parent)
```

It will produce a Hash something like the following:

```
# { 
#   parent1 => [category1, category2],
#   parent2 => [category3]
# }

# or

{#<Parent:0x007fa92582f930 @name="Parent1">=>
  [#<Category:0x007fa92582f868
    @name="Category1",
    @parent=#<Parent:0x007fa92582f930 @name="Parent1">>,
   #<Category:0x007fa92582f7c8
    @name="Category2",
    @parent=#<Parent:0x007fa92582f930 @name="Parent1">>],
 #<Parent:0x007fa92582f8b8 @name="Parent1">=>
  [#<Category:0x007fa92582f750
    @name="Category3",
    @parent=#<Parent:0x007fa92582f8b8 @name="Parent1">>]}
```

And with that you iterate over each Parent and its grouped Categories to render in your view template like so:

```
<% @categories.group_by(&:parent).each do |parent, categories| %>
  <h4><%= parent.name if parent %></h4>
  <% categories.each do |category| %>
    <%= category.name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could accomplish something like :

```
<% parents.each do |parent| %>
  <h4><%= parent.name %></h4>
  <% parent.children.each do |child| %>
    <%= child.name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

So for your example :

```
<% @categories.parents.each do |parent| %>
  <h4><%= parent.name %></h4>
  <% parent.children.each do |category| %>
    <%= category.name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Depending on the name of the parent of your category model, you could also do :

```
Parent.tree_view(:name)
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is `category.parent`? If it isn't nil or explicitly false, then `<h4><%= category.parent.name if category.parent %></h4>` will always display `category.parent.name`, because the if statement is essential checking whether `category.parent` exists. And assuming a parent exists for each child, it will display the parent each time. You'll have to change the if statement.

Sorry I couldn't be of more help, perhaps I could give a suggestion if you edit the post to include the code from `category` or `parent`.

Comment: The categories without parents are root categories.

Answer (score 0):

Here what I come with.

```
<% @categories.roots.each do |parent| %>
  <h4><%= category.parent.name %></h4>
  <% parent.children.each do |child| %>
    <%= parent.name %> <%= child.name%>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

However, this work for 1 level categories only.
If you want deep level categories, you may need to define a recursive method for that.